Touch Screen doesn't work with X11 enabled on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Morning,
I've installed Ubuntu desktop (24.04.1 LTS) on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 gen 3 Tablet.  Install went fine without any errors or issues.
I'd written a python application using PYQT6 libraries and tested this on another desktop with same OS although no touch screen.
Env:
PyQT6
Python 3.12
Ubuntu 24.04.1
Graphics card on tablet: intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
Built an single application file with Pyinstaller and copied all the distribution contents to a USB and moved to a directory on the tablet.
I changed the windowing system from wayland to X11 from login screen, also after my issues I switched to wayland and found my windows where all messed up so I switched back to X11.
When running my application my touchscreen would only work with wayland not X11.
Does X11 not have touch capabilities ?  I did some googling and didn't find anything saying it doesn't.  Wayland although providing touch capabilities messes up my application too much to consider using.
Any suggestions / information greatly appreciated.
xinput:

xev:


I can say X11 does have touch capabilities as I use flavor desktops that use X.org and can use the touchscreen; but capabilities can vary between Wayland and X.org (as well as kernel module (driver) support possibly too)

I have a similar problem.  I am just updated Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 on a Thinkpad X1 gen 2 tablet.  Both touchscreen and stylus worked well in 22.04 when I did "Ubuntu on xorg" and did not use Wayland.  I am using "Ubuntu on xorg" now on 24.04 and the stylus works only intermittently.  The touchscreen is basically unusable.  I can sometimes scroll using the touchscreen but not reliably.  I cannot move a window by touching and dragging its title bar.  I cannot move cards in a card game.  Using xev I can see that the touchscreen registers every touch that I give but I cannot use it.

@weave.  Here are some things you can do to get more information.  You could post the output of xinput.  You could run xev and see if screen touches generate events.

I think the X11 thinkpad tablet was a failed attempt by Lenovo to compete with the Microsoft's Surface Pro, although I read lots of complaints about it's quality as well. Might come down to a poor quality (cheap) touch screen itself.

I have lenovo T490S touch screen, I usually use wayland most of my time and touch screen works fine with one finger touch, i faced same problem for long time when I switch to X11, after many tries i observed that when I touch screen with 2 fingers it works, i can scroll, open, close , do all the tasks on the touch screen with 2 fingers, I thought it s configuration issue, am trying to figure it out .

Wayland just wasn't an option for me until a similar post I'd entered on PythonGuis site was responded to suggesting Gnome should have an extension that can center windows and handle window options...... sure enough Gnome Tweaks provides this option and with some modifications to my code I'm now able to run my app under Wayland.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
